# D'Hondt method calculator with php?

Tags: php, xml

Hi everyone i have problem with my project, let me explain.I can drag the data to the file xml but can't read the allocated number of seats that are required via the D'Hondt method. I' ve give it a try a lot of times but couldn't do it. Can someone give me any help?

here is the my code

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($xml->city as $city) {
    echo '<tr><th>';
    echo $xml->city[$i]->attributes(). "</th>";
    echo '<th>Votes</th><th>Seats:';
    echo $city->total_seats.'</th></tr>';
    foreach ($xml->city[$i]->party_votes as $party_votes) {
            foreach ($party_votes as $party_votes) {
                echo '<tr style="color:'.$color[$i].'"><td>';
                echo $party_votes->attributes()."</td><td> ";
                echo $citya[$i]=$party_votes->total_votes. "</td>";
            }
    }
    $i++;
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

here is the xml file

```html
 <city id="City A">
   <total_seats>8</total_seats>
   <party_votes>
  <party id ="Party A">
   <total_votes>100000</total_votes>
  </party>
  <party id ="Party B">
   <total_votes>80000</total_votes>
  </party>
  <party id ="Party C">
   <total_votes>30000</total_votes>
  </party>
  <party id ="Party D">
   <total_votes>20000</total_votes>
  </party>
   </party_votes>
   </city>
   <city id="City B">
   <total_seats>6</total_seats>
   <party_votes>
  <party id ="Party A">
   <total_votes>10000</total_votes>
  </party>
  <party id ="Party B">
   <total_votes>50000</total_votes>
  </party>
  <party id ="Party C">
   <total_votes>40000</total_votes>
  </party>
  <party id ="Party D">
   <total_votes>30000</total_votes>
  </party>
   </party_votes>
   </city>
```

How to implement the D'Hondt method to allocate seats to votes in Php?

Comment: Which variant of the D’Hondt method did you try? There are at least five different yet equivialent variants.

Comment: I wanna do this example 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Hondt_method

Comment: Per city or do you want to sum all seats and all votes and _then_ distribute the seats? An example result for the sampe data you've provided would be nice.

Comment: Per each city according to their number of seats
http://i.hizliresim.com/v5n7MO.png

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the values from the xml document and generating the D'Hondt distribution are two separate problems. I'll concentrate on the latter. 
Here is an example using a [generator function](http://docs.php.net/generators) and a [SplPriorityQueue](http://docs.php.net/class.splpriorityqueue).

```
<?php
function gen_dhondt(array $results) {
    // using SplPriorityQueue as a sorted listed
    $foo = new SplPriorityQueue;
    $foo->setExtractFlags(SplPriorityQueue::EXTR_DATA);
    // initialize the list
    foreach( $results as $party=>$votes ) {
        $foo->insert(['name'=>$party, 'div'=>1, 'votes'=>$votes], $votes);
    }

    // get the element with the highest votes/divisor
    foreach( $foo as $next ) {
        // re-enqueue this element with ++divisor
        ++$next['div'];
        $foo->insert($next, $next['votes']/$next['div']);

        // "return" the name of this element
        yield $next['name'];
    }
}


$seats = 8;
$results = array('C'=>30000, 'B'=>80000, 'A'=>100000, 'D'=>20000);

// a) just show the order in which the seats are distributed
$lit = new LimitIterator( gen_dhondt($results), 0, $seats);
foreach( $lit as $p ) {
    echo $p, "\r\n";
}

// b) count the seats
var_export(
    array_count_values(
        iterator_to_array(
            new LimitIterator( gen_dhondt($results), 0, $seats)
        )
    )
);
```

prints

```
A
B
A
B
A
C
B
A
array (
  'A' => 4,
  'B' => 3,
  'C' => 1,
)
```

(keep in mind that a) and b) are two completely separate runs; if you want you *can* combine them in a slightly more efficient way - but this example isn't optimized for efficiency at all....)

Comment: Thanks for explaining but I've tried to do it with ne own code which I couldn't work out. Do you know how to work it with my code?